# Bayesian Network in Pomegranate: ValueError: Sample does not have the same number of dimensions as the model

Tags: bayesian-networks, pomegranate

I am trying to model a Bayesian Network in python using Pomegranate package. The network should be learned from data. So I am using .from_samples method. However I am having trouble using the method .predict_proba() and it gives me error.

This is how I build the model:

```
model = BayesianNetwork.from_samples(X_train, algorithm='chow-liu')
```

and this is how I do prediction:

```
model.predict_proba(X_train)
```

and this is the error I get:

ValueError: Sample does not have the same number of dimensions as the model. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer: you should define your state_names when calling the from_samples method.

Another question is how do we do classification using this model?

Answer (score 0):

you should use predict() method to predict the state of the not-valued nodes.

Check the [documentation](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BayesianNetwork.html#prediction) for more details. 
Also, in the [repository](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate) you can find some interesting tutorials that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please add [] around the sample you are passing